# Attach a external file as attachement using wp_mail

Tags: attachments, email, wp-mail

I am trying to attach external file link (doc file) as attachment but not able to so .. no attachment is being attached..

```
$email_attachment =  array('https://ucarecdn.com/8aa17c61-bd55-4311-8b45-7d9a2efde6c5/');
wp_mail($admin_email,$email_subject,$email_message,$headers,$email_attachment);
```

Please help I am stuck

Comment: Probably need to use an absolute path in your url.

Comment: Also, make sure the content type is set to text/html. See wp_mail_content_type

Answer (score 1):

You can't attach from a URL.  So `https://ucarecdn.com/8aa17c61-bd55-4311-8b45-7d9a2efde6c5/` won't work.

You need an absolute path to the file, such as `/path/to/my/file.ext`.

But there are some other problems with your code snippet as well.  You use `$email_attachement` (with a ..ch**e**ment...) in one place, but then `$email_attachment` in your `wp_mail()` call.  Also, your "attachment" isn't a file.  While that may resolve as a URL, that would involve a URL rewrite which isn't going to work for accessing a file to attach.

Comment: thanks for your inputs.. please excuse the spelling mistakes . i have edited it above.. but how do i get started .. so do I create the temporary file from contents of the doc file on the url and then use it .. not getting how to move forward

Comment: After re-reading your question (and the title), it seems like the file is remote (not on the same server)?  There's not a direct way to do that. You'd need to incorporate a process of retrieving the file and saving it locally so you could attach it.